# Am I breaking the non-compete clause of my job contract?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms, breach-of-contract

Suppose that a person W is about to start an internship at a company C soon, W just signed the contract.  one of the clauses reads:

> During the term of this contract, the Employee must not carry out any
> activities directly or indirectly in competition with *company_name*.
> The Employee must not have a direct or indirect interest in any
> businesses which compete with *company_name* or with which *company_name* has a business relationship.

This is an internship contract, therefore it has a defined end date.

Additionally, suppose that W has signed a contract with another company D, to start working there once the internship finishes (the dates of both contracts do not overlap at any time). This other work is in a very similar position to the one W will  have in the internship but is regular employment.

I know W can not work for another company while doing the internship (because of the clause stated above), but my question is: Is having a contract on another similar company, for once the internship finishes, considered "an indirect interest in a business that competes with *company_name*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is having a contract on another similar company, for once the internship finishes, considered "an indirect interest in a business that competes with company_name"?

No. For purposes of the internship contract, you have no interests in the second company: Whatever happens to that company during your internship is largely inconsequential to you and to your performance at the internship.

Additionally, the similarity of both positions does not imply that the companies are competitors or have a business relationship.

The terms of the clause encompass only the duration of the internship. It cannot be construed in a way that restricts your freedom of contract once the internship ends.